# Cake php RESTfull POST method not working

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my controller function accepting only two parameters user_id,location.

```
class UserLocationsController extends AppController {

 public function add() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->UserLocation->create();
        if ($this->UserLocation->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user location has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->UserLocation->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));

}


}
```

when submit the form it is successfully save to data base.but I need to use this with rest client.(without form).I tested it with user_id and location parameters and post method but not saved data to DB.

```
    $this->request->data
```

is empty when try with rest client. how can I save data without form?

Comment: Have you added `Router::mapResources('user_location');
Router::parseExtensions();` in your `config/routes.php` file to allow rest on your project ?

Comment: Yes, Get methods are working fine as json