# How to send post data to cake php rest route?

Tags: rest, cakephp

I'm creating restfull web services with cake php.it is workig for **index,view** method with json format.my problem is with  **add** method.

I am trying to post data like this

```
url: http://localhost/locationApp/details.json
```

parameters:user_id=7
           location=90

but it is not save data to DB ($this->request->data) is null .why is that? this is working  fine with webpage.

this is my add function

```
 public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {



            $this->Detail->create();    
            pr($this->request->data);die;
            if ($this->Detail->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The detail has been saved.'));


                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));



            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The detail could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }



        }


}
```

Comment: Please don't double post, instead edit your original question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502371/cake-php-restfull-post-method-not-working

Comment: check you have sending data using post method only